# Constructor not throwing new exception?

Tags: java, exception, constructor

Why won’t this code throw an exception? Have tried a lot of things but when I test it with a JUnit class like this, for example, it won’t throw an exception:

```
Vehicle e = new Vehicle('C', 'G', "A1234");
```

```
// Constructor
public Vehicle(char kType, char dType, String regNr) {
    String temp0 = regNr.substring(0, 2);
    String temp = regNr.substring(2);
    boolean finish = false;

    if ("" + kType == "C") {
        for (char c : temp0.toCharArray()) {
            if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("3");
            }
        }

        if (temp.length() == 5) {
            finish = true;
        } else {
            finish = false;
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("4");
        }

        try {
            Integer.parseInt(temp);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            finish = false;
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("5");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if(""+kType=="C")`??? Why not just `if(kType=='C')`?

Comment: @barakmanos In order to make the whole code pointless?

Comment: Besides: you want us to spend **our** time to help you. So **you** please spend the 1 minute it takes to properly format/indent your source code; instead of dumping this **mess** on us.

Comment: @GhostCat: I did not understand your comment/question.

Comment: Just for the record: even when your question got closed as duplicate, you still can accept my answer if you find it helpful. And I think it is, as it definitely addresses your actual question ...

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't.

```
if(""+kType=="C"){
```

that code will always give you false.

You (almost) **never** compare strings using ==; you have to use the `equals()` method. And then of course, when your if block is really entered, there are various conditions that can lead to throwing of those IllegalArgumentExceptions.